# SQL: Counting Combinations of Distinct Years

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
    name VARCHAR(50),
    year INTEGER
    country VARCHAR(50),
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student1', 2010, 'usa');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student1', 2010, 'usa');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student1', 2013, 'canada');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student2', 2013, 'uk');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student3', 2020, 'usa');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student3', 2021, 'uk');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student3', 2022, 'uk');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country  )
VALUES ('student4', 2009, 'usa');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name, year, country )
VALUES ('student5', 2010, 'usa');

    name     year   country
1 student1   2010      usa
2 student1   2010      usa
3 student1   2013    canada
4 student2   2013       uk
5 student3   2020      usa
6 student3   2021      uk
7 student3   2022       uk
8 student4   2009      usa
9 student5   2010    usa
```

**My Question:** I want to perform the following steps in this table:

**Step 1:** First, I want to identify the country associated with each student in the earliest available year for that student - then, count the number of distinct years for that  student:

```
      name earliest_year earliest_country number_of_distinct_years
 student1          2010              usa                        2
 student2          2013               uk                        1
 student3          2020              usa                        3
 student4          2009              usa                        1
 student5          2010              usa                        1
```

**Step 2:** Then, I want to remove all rows where the earliest year is less than or equal to  2010:

```
      name earliest_year earliest_country number_of_distinct_years
 student1          2010              usa                        2
 student2          2013               uk                        1
 student3          2020              usa                        3
 student5          2010              usa                        1
```

**Step 3:** Finally, I want to count the number of combinations of earliest_country and number_of_distinct_years:

```
#expected results
  country number_of_distinct_years count
     usa                        1     1
     usa                        2     1
     usa                        3     1
      uk                        1     1
```

Here is my attempt to solve this problem:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 AS SELECT name,
MIN(year) AS earliest_year, 
MIN(country) AS earliest_country, 
COUNT(DISTINCT year) AS number_of_distinct_years
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY name;

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE earliest_year >= 2010;

    CREATE TABLE FINAL_TABLE AS SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTS, 
number_of_distinct_years, earliest_country FROM TABLE2
    GROUP BY  number_of_distinct_years, earliest_country;
```

Here is everything in a single query:

```
WITH TABLE1 AS (
    SELECT name,
    MIN(year) AS earliest_year, 
    MIN(country) AS earliest_country, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT year) AS number_of_distinct_years
    FROM MY_TABLE
    GROUP BY name
),
TABLE2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE earliest_year >= 2010
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTS, 
number_of_distinct_years, earliest_country 
FROM TABLE2
GROUP BY number_of_distinct_years, earliest_country;
```

The above code runs, but is not producing the correct output:

```
  COUNTS number_of_distinct_years earliest_country
      1                        2           canada
      1                        1               uk
      1                        3               uk
      1                        1              usa
```

Can someone please show me how to correct this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** After much trial and error, I think I was finally be able to figure it out?

```
WITH earliest_year AS (
    SELECT name, MIN(year) AS earliest_year
    FROM MY_TABLE
    GROUP BY name
),
earliest_country AS (
    SELECT e.name, e.earliest_year, m.country AS earliest_country
    FROM earliest_year e
    JOIN MY_TABLE m
    ON e.name = m.name AND e.earliest_year = m.year
),
number_of_years AS (
    SELECT e.name, e.earliest_year, e.earliest_country, COUNT(DISTINCT m.year) AS number_of_distinct_years
    FROM earliest_country e
    JOIN MY_TABLE m
    ON e.name = m.name
    GROUP BY e.name, e.earliest_year, e.earliest_country
),
filtered_years AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM number_of_years
    WHERE earliest_year >= 2010
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, earliest_country, number_of_distinct_years
FROM filtered_years
GROUP BY earliest_country, number_of_distinct_years;

  count earliest_country number_of_distinct_years
     1              usa                        2
     1               uk                        1
     1              usa                        3
     1              usa                        1
```

Comment: If it produces the right result then it is correct. I’m not sure why you asked this question and what sort of answer you are expecting

Comment: @NickW: Thank you for your reply! Often times, I find that my code works for a specific problem - but it will not take into consideration some "fringe cases". Thus, even though I am getting the desired result - I just wanted to confirm if this logic will in fact work for all cases. Thank you so much!

Comment: Spoiler alert: I believe this to have at least one bug, as well as potential performance problems.

Comment: We're back to where we were with the previous question. Why would you expect that the output have three distinct years for USA on one student? The maximum number of distinct years within the USA for any given student is 1.

Comment: i can't see how you get meaningful result on the first query. `min(country)` will just give you the first country alphabetically, regardless of the year. So, you'll get years and countries mixed up.

Comment: @Reinderien : Thank you for your reply! I am now realizing this myself... I am thinking of an approach using the PARTITION function which can be used to create a rank variable denoting the earliest available year for each student....

Comment: @Reinderien : The expected results are the results produced at the end of step 3

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out... please see the update. thank you so much for all the reviews you have provided - much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy that you were able to reform your query to make it work, but it probably shouldn't be written as it is now. Avoid CTEs because they represent an optimization boundary in some database systems.

```sql
create table my_table(
    name varchar(50) not null,
    year smallint not null check(year between 1900 and 2200),
    country varchar(50) not null
);

insert into my_table(name, year, country) values
('student1', 2010, 'usa'),
('student1', 2010, 'usa'),
('student1', 2013, 'canada'),
('student2', 2013, 'uk'),
('student3', 2020, 'usa'),
('student3', 2021, 'uk'),
('student3', 2022, 'uk'),
('student4', 2009, 'usa'),
('student5', 2010, 'usa');

select count(*) as count, *
from (
    select earliest_country,
        count(distinct m.year) as number_of_distinct_years
    from (
        select distinct on(name) name, year as earliest_year, country as earliest_country
        from my_table
        order by name, year
    ) as e
    join my_table m on e.name = m.name
                   and e.earliest_year >= 2010
    group by e.name, e.earliest_year, e.earliest_country
) as filtered_years
group by earliest_country, number_of_distinct_years;
```

This produces the same results.

Comment: @Reindeirien: thank you for your answer! I am working on a related question - can you please take a look if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708678/sql-finding-out-all-possible-combinations-of-years-per-id-per-group thank you so much !