# SQL: Finding Out All Possible Combinations of Years Per ID per Group

Tags: sql, netezza

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following dataset ("my_table") about students (over the years 2010-2015), the current degree major they are enrolled in, the date than an exam was taken, and the exam result:

```
    student_id current_major year exam_result
1            1       Science 2010           0
2            1          Arts 2013           1
3            1          Arts 2013           0
4            2       Science 2010           1
5            2          Arts 2011           1
6            2       Science 2013           1
7            3          Arts 2010           1
8            3          Arts 2015           1
9            4          Arts 2010           0
10           4       Science 2013           1
11           5          Arts 2010           0
12           5          Arts 2011           0
13           5       Science 2012           1
```

**My Question:** I want to find out if the **initial** degree that a student started with affects how many years the students stayed in the university. (The period of analysis is from 2010 to 2015 - a student could join the university anywhere between 2010 and 2015.)

To answer this question, I first wanted to make a table that shows the number of students that attended the college for each combination of years:

```
select year_2010,
 year_2011,
year_2012,
 year_2013,
 year_2014,
 year_2015, 
count(*) 
from
(
select student_id,
max(case when (year = 2010) then 1 else 0 end) as 'year_2010',
max(case when (year = 2011) then 1 else 0 end) as 'year_2011',
max(case when (year = 2012) then 1 else 0 end) as 'year_2012',
max(case when (year = 2013) then 1 else 0 end) as 'year_2013',
max(case when (year = 2014) then 1 else 0 end) as 'year_2014',
max(case when (year = 2015) then 1 else 0 end) as 'year_2015',
from my_table
group by student_id)a
group by year_2010,
 year_2011,
 year_2012,
 year_2013,
 year_2014,
 year_2015;


   year_2010 year_2011 year_2012 year_2013 year_2014 year_2015 count_star()
1          0         1         0         1         0         0           24
2          0         0         0         0         1         1           17
3          0         0         1         1         0         0           22
4          1         1         1         0         0         0           12
5          0         1         1         1         1         0           12
6          1         0         0         0         1         0           23
7          0         0         1         0         0         0           49
```

**My Problem:** **Now, I want to "group" this table using the earliest available major for each student** (i.e. what was the student studying in their first recorded year at the university). For the sake of this problem, let's assume that a student can not change their major in the first year and must wait until at least the second year to do this. **However, from the second year onwards, a student can switch their degree major multiple times within the same year.**

I would like to answer questions such as:

- Of the students who enrolled in the university in 2010 and initially started studying sciences - how many of these students studied 5 consecutive years?
- Of the students who enrolled in the university in 2011 and initially started studying arts - how many of these students studied at least 2 years between 2011 and 2015?

I think that such questions can be answered by:

- Step 1: Using a PARTITION function to find out the earliest year (via a CTE)
- Step 2: Using the existing query
- Step 3: Joining the results from Step 1 and Step 2 together

Here is my attempt to do this:

```
WITH earliest_major AS (
    SELECT student_id, current_major AS earliest_major
    FROM (
        SELECT student_id, current_major, year,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY year) AS rn
        FROM my_table
    ) sub
    WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT em.earliest_major,
       year_2010,
       year_2011,
       year_2012,
       year_2013,
       year_2014,
       year_2015, 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT student_id,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (year = 2010) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_2010,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (year = 2011) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_2011,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (year = 2012) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_2012,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (year = 2013) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_2013,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (year = 2014) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_2014,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (year = 2015) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_2015
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY student_id
) a
JOIN earliest_major em ON a.student_id = em.student_id
GROUP BY em.earliest_major, 
         year_2010, 
         year_2011, 
         year_2012, 
         year_2013, 
         year_2014, 
         year_2015;
```

The query seems to run and produce results in the desired format:

```
  earliest_major year_2010 year_2011 year_2012 year_2013 year_2014 year_2015 count_star()
1         Science         0         1         0         1         0         0           15
2            Arts         0         0         0         0         1         1           11
3            Arts         0         0         1         1         0         0           13
4            Arts         1         1         1         0         0         0            8
5         Science         0         1         1         1         1         0            7
```

**But I am not sure if my logic is correct - can someone please help me with this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Is your output correct? If not, what do you actually expect? If instead you know your output to be correct, this is a question for Code Review and not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should drop your columnar format and your cases. You effectively want a histogram. It's preferable for this to be in "long" format; the application layer can reformat that if necessary.

```sql
create table major_exams(
  student_id int not null,
  current_major text not null,
  year smallint not null check (year between 1900 and 2200),
  exam_result boolean not null
);

insert into major_exams(student_id, current_major, year, exam_result) values
( 1, 'Science', 2010, false),
( 1,    'Arts', 2013, true),
( 1,    'Arts', 2013, false),
( 2, 'Science', 2010, true),
( 2,    'Arts', 2011, true),
( 2, 'Science', 2013, true),
( 3,    'Arts', 2010, true),
( 3,    'Arts', 2015, true),
( 4,    'Arts', 2010, false),
( 4, 'Science', 2013, true),
( 5,    'Arts', 2010, false),
( 5,    'Arts', 2011, false),
( 5, 'Science', 2012, true);

select major, duration, count(*) as n
from (
    select first_majors.major,
        last_majors.year - first_majors.year + 1 as duration
    from (
        select distinct on (student_id) student_id, current_major as major, year
        from major_exams
        order by student_id, year
    ) first_majors
    join (
        select student_id, max(year) as year
        from major_exams
        group by student_id
    ) last_majors on last_majors.student_id = first_majors.student_id
) major_bounds
group by major, duration
order by major, duration;
```

```
major       duration    n
Arts        3           1
Arts        4           1
Arts        6           1
Science     4           2
```